# Microsoft Graph API - collect data from someone who is not an admin

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

We are using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members` to fetch member details from a customer. If the member is an admin - they get a permission popup and on consent we are able to see member details such as their relevant users, group info and so on.

This does not happen when a non-admin member tries to login. It says: Need admin approval.

Is there a way to bypass this and get user details irrespective of admin consent?

Thanks,
Billy

Comment: Are you trying from Graph Explorer or using any application?

Comment: We are using an application created in Azure AD

Answer (score 1):

Admin consent required for `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members`

[Admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow) gives admins a secure way to grant access to applications that require admin approval. When a user tries to access an application but is unable to provide consent, they can send a request for admin approval.

You can try demon application, you get a token from Azure AD in its own name (without a user), and then calls the Microsoft Graph /users endpoint to get the list of users, which it then displays (as JSON blob).please refer this [document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph)

Comment: Ok I get the fact that we need admin consent for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members

Comment: I tried a deamon app for web: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-daemon-webapp   ---    the one you sent is for console and we get one for web as ours is a web application. Even here it asks for admin consent.

Comment: We can't access user information without admin consent approval.